# Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs (errors.js:25) at

Tags: solidity, react

I am always getting this erros with get calls i am using React, Truffle, metamask and Ganache

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs (errors.js:25) at SolidityFunction../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js.SolidityFunction.validateArgs (function.js:74) at SolidityFunction../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js.SolidityFunction.toPayload (function.js:90)at SolidityFunction../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js.SolidityFunction.call (function.js:131) 
>   at contract.js:135
>   at new Promise ()

React:

```
changeLastName(e){
e.preventDefault();
let id = e.target.dataset.somefield;
this.contarct.getLastName(id).call().then((lastName)=>{

this.setState({lastName:lastName});
```

solidity:

```
struct {
string lastName;

}
getLastName(unit256 _id)public view returns (string){
unit256 id = customersIndex[_id];
return customers[id].lastName;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about this but check compatibility between your solc compiler and the backing chain.

The Byzantium fork is a protocol change that includes changes to the interface. In order to work with a post-fork blockchain, you need to use solc 0.4.22 or better. If your backing chain is not Byzantium, then you need to use solc 0.4.21 or less.

If the two sides are not a match, then you will have head-scratcher trouble at the interface level.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Rob if the contract abi didn't match what the contract is expecting it will cause this problem. Try regenerating the contract abi or making sure it is the correct one.

If the abi is the correct one another common cause with javascript is that the value passed as parameter is `undefined`. For example when the name of the field is wrong, ie you missed or typed wrong a single letter, or perhaps the user didn't fill a field on the form.

My first approach with this problem is to log all the parameters passed to the function to ensure they are not `undefined` and set them to he right values.